# How to retrieve user entered input in adaptive card in java

Tags: java, adaptive-cards

Attached the JSON of adaptive card I sent in teams.

```
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.0",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Publish Adaptive Card schema",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "size": "medium"
            },
            {
                "type": "ColumnSet",
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "auto",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "Image",
                                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg",
                                "size": "medium",
                                "style": "person"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Column",
                        "width": "stretch",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "Matt Hidinger",
                                "weight": "bolder",
                                "wrap": true
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "spacing": "none",
                                "text": "Created Tuesday, Feb 14, 2017",
                                "isSubtle": true,
                                "wrap": true
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "Now that we have defined the main rules and features of the format, we need to produce a schema and publish it to GitHub. The schema will be the starting point of our reference documentation.",
                "wrap": true
            },
            {
                "type": "FactSet",
                "facts": [
                    {
                        "title": "Board:",
                        "value": "Adaptive Card"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "List:",
                        "value": "Backlog"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Assigned to:",
                        "value": "Matt Hidinger"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Due date:",
                        "value": "Not set"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
],
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "Set due date",
        "card": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "Input.Date",
                    "id": "dueDate",
                    "title": "Select due date"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.ShowCard",
        "title": "Comment",
        "card": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "Input.Text",
                    "id": "comment",
                    "isMultiline": true,
                    "placeholder": "Enter your comment"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "OK"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "View",
        "url": "http://adaptivecards.io"
    }
]
```

}

After User entered values and click ok, reply from bot is "Echo:"

How can i display the entered value as reply from bot.

I have implemented this to get activity, but this method is not called when use click ok.

Comment: I  have implemented this, but its not called   protected CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageActivity(TurnContext turnContext) {
     LOGGER.debug("Incoming message from bot");

        return turnContext.sendActivity(
                MessageFactory.text("From Bot : " + turnContext.getActivity().getText())
        ).thenApply(sendResult -> null);
    }

Comment: Have you found the answer? If yes, then you can post your own answer to help others.